# Multiple tags with Java not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

multiple tags with Java as the first tag are not working.
E.G. /questions/tagged/java+parallel-processing
Everything after Java is lost. Been this way for two days now.

Windows7(64), Firefox and Chrome

Comment: After posting this question, it seems to be working correctly again. Thank you.

Comment: Odd problem.  Works when I'm logged in, doesn't work when I'm logged out.  Sure looks like a bug.  Try it again after logging out, update your question with what you see.

Comment: Confirmed that when not logged in, you are redirected to the first tag. This is not limited to just [tag:java]; the same happens if you use [tag:python], for example.

Comment: [Related bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when).

Answer (score 11):

This happens for *any* combination of tags *if you are not logged in*.

If you are not a logged in user, you are redirected to the first tag only. It doesn't matter what that first tag *is*, you are simply redirected to limit the page to just the one tag. In other words, there is nothing special about the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag here; you see the same behaviour for `/questions/tagged/foo+bar+spam`; you'll be redirected to `/questions/tagged/foo`, which doesn't exist.

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), a scalability measure of sorts to limit load on the database, see Shog9's answer to the related bug report:

> Requests from anonymous users to some of these routes were causing an
>   unacceptably large performance hit a few days ago, potentially hurting
>   the experience for many other users.
>
> As a result, they were disabled for anonymous users. They may be
>   re-enabled at some point when we have had time to implement a less
>   drastic solution.

If you want to do a multi-tag search, log in.

Comment: It worked without logging in for years. I often jump around without being logged in to multiple forums. Saves a lot of trouble. When I find something I can help with, then I log in. A real pain in the xxx.

Comment: This answer is correct; this is a recent change, to counter some very persistent attacks a few days ago. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when/275338#275338