# Is the searching for tags working?

Tags: bug, search

This question seems similar to these three below, but they relate to the bahaviours when logged-in versus logged-out. My question is applies when logged-in.

[Searching for questions based on multiple tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275467/searching-for-questions-based-on-multiple-tags)

[Multiple tags with Java not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275311/multiple-tags-with-java-not-working)

[Content does NOT change when changing tabs on /tagged for a particular tag when NOT logged in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when)

---

Searching on Stackoverflow for `[c#] [regex]` should find items having both of these tags but it appears to be doing an `or` and finding items with either tag. Comparing the top few results from the two searches `[c#] [regex]` and `[c#] or [regex]` gives the same results, very few of the found items contain both tags.

The help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching has a section titled "OR Operator" to discuss the `or` operator. There is nothing about an `and` operator. Searching for `[c#] and [regex]` appears to only find items with both tags, but it also looks for the word `and`. The top right corner of the results page shows:

[image: results found containing "and" tagged with _c#_ _regex_]

A possibly related behaviour: Three of my saved searches that worked a month or two ago are now consistently reporting "**That's a miss** *Sorry, that filter combination has no results. Please try different criteria.*". The URLs used are these:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-testing+-jmeter+-yandex

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance+-jmeter+-yandex

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance-testing+-jmeter+-yandex

The search box in the top line of the result page has reordered the tags so it shows these values: `-[jmeter] [performance] -[yandex]` and `-[jmeter] [load-testing] -[yandex]` and `-[jmeter] [performance-testing] -[yandex]`.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're mentioning- Are you by chance using the new nav? If you are, it could potentially have something to do with that. (From what I understand search works a little differently with the new nav.)

Comment: If you are using the new nav, [tag searching is kinda broken at the moment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261422/280467)

Comment: There are **any** (show questions with any of the tags) and **all** (show questions with all the tags) buttons at the top of the new nav.

Comment: Yes I am using the new nav, my searches had not found the link just provided by @ryanyuyu, so thank you for that link.

Comment: Thank you @BilltheLizard for pointing out the any and all buttons.